# C programming switch case what is wrong?

Tags: c

I have to write using switch case a program which finds if a number is smaller than 10,equals to 10,bigger than 10 and smaller than 100 and different from the above options.The number is given by the user.
I tried this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()


switch ( 4*(n >= 100) + 2*(n >= 10) + (n <= 10) )
{
case 1: printf( "%d is less than 10\n", n); break;

case 3: printf( "%d is equal to 10\n", n); break;

case 2: printf( "10 < %d < 100\n", n); break;

default: printf(" %d is not in an identified range\n", n); break;
}
```

But when I try to compile it, it says :

```
ERROR IN "switch ( 4*(n >= 100) + 2*(n >= 10) + (n <= 10) ) ".
```

Where is the error? I need to write this in switch.

The error: `D:\comparison.c syntax error before "switch"`.

Comment: No need to write in all caps.

Comment: Is your switch just below main? Is there really no opening bracket for your main?

Comment: And is there really no declaration of `n`? At least post the **REAL** error message *exactly* as it is shown to you.

Comment: Remember that if you're posting a question about compiler errors, then please include the _complete_ and _unedited_ errors.

Comment: For the given conditions wouldn't an `if` statement be more clear?

Comment: I need this in switch.AND sorry for the caps.

Comment: Again, is this the *exact* code, beginning with, and including, the declaration of `main()`? Do *not* post "it looks like this" snippets when you have compilation errors. Post **exact** code or we can't help you. And we're still waiting on the **exact** error message.

Comment: I posted the exact error message.This is THE WHOLE code.

Comment: Thanks,guy with cute dimples.

Comment: Now it shows another error -_- .It says that n is not declared :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your *exact* code, then the following is wrong:

- There is no opening brace past the declaration of `main()`. Therefore there is no function *body* and you're code is now sitting in the middle of global namespace.
- There is also not declaration of the variable `n`, therefore it too, will cause a compilation error.
- Finally, there is no return value for `main()`, which while not a compilation error (unless warnings are sufficiently pedantic) it is a logic error and leaves the return value for `main()` with undefined behavior.

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{ // <<==== note: added opening curly brace

    int n=65; // <<==== note: added declaration of n

    switch ( 4*(n >= 100) + 2*(n >= 10) + (n <= 10) )
    {
        case 1: printf( "%d is less than 10\n", n); break;
        case 3: printf( "%d is equal to 10\n", n); break;
        case 2: printf( "10 < %d < 100\n", n); break;
        default: printf(" %d is not in an identified range\n", n); break;
    }

    return 0; // <<==== note: added return value
} // <<== note: added closing curly brace
```

I leave whether the actual expressions in your `switch` condition are correct or not to you (I don't think they are, but I am not familiar with your assignment).

Comment: @user2304286 How to populate `n` from user input is a different issue and a different question. Your question was about why your code would not compile. These are the reasons why.

Comment: @user2304286 very hard to read code of that magnitude in comments, but   it looks correct (at least the declaration of `n` and the `scanf()` call. You should test the return value of `scanf()` to ensure it did, in fact, successfully parse an integer from your input. See the documentation for [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Answer (score 1):

If that's your whole code, you are missing braces `{` and `}` around the function.

You should also add a `return 0;` statement at the end of the function, as you declare the function to return an integer. And if you don't take any arguments, you should declare the function with a `void` argument.

Comment: Excuse my IQ,but can you give me a hint on how to change the expression?

Comment: @user2304286 The expression is actually alright for what you want to do, the error is something _completely_ different.